# Java extract text from job descriptions (Regex OR Pattern)

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

In my text there will be content like:

```
2 years of experiences of databse, XXXBBXBXB 3 years databse and sql experiences, 
UUYFS 3 year experiences, 4 yeears databse contract, 5 years contract
```

What I want is to find the pattern of and get the single digit before the pattern:

```
1: years of experience
2: year of experiences
...
```

There will be the case that some text will be between the 'years' and 'experience'. And it might be appear as 'years' OR 'year' OR 'year experiences' and so on.

But the final output will be looks like: (excluding the digits with other patterns like 'years contract' and so on)

```
2, 3, 3
```

I tried something like '\years\experience', but seems it is wrong.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
(\d+)\s+years?\s+.*?\s+experience
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. But it seems a wrong regex when I paste into the Pattern.compile() method...

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. This solves majorly the problem. But when the content is like "3 years data base contract asdfasd 2 year databse and sql experiences". It extract the entire sentence instead of only "2 years databse and sql experiences". Thx

Comment: Yeah, I think it's almost impossible to come up with a pattern that matches all the different cases you're trying to match.

Comment: @XingshengGuo How are getting the digits from this pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Try with below regex

```
(\d+)\s+(year|years)
```

[image]

Get the digit at group 1 using [Matcher#group()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) that looks for the groups enclosed in parenthesis ().

Read more about [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

#### [DEMO](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yCW_wE76qA7dmBOv)

Sample code:

```
String url = "2 years of experiences of databse, XXXBBXBXB 3 years databse and sql experiences, UUYFS 3 year experiences";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(year|years)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

output:

```
2
3
3
```

#### EDIT:

Try below pattern as per your comment:

```
(\d+)\s+(years of experience|year experience)
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. But this seems just captured the pattern of 'X years'. Sometimes, there will text like '3 years contract', which is not what I want. So the 'experience' have to be within the pattern. And sometimes it will be text between them and sometimes not. Thx again

Comment: OK Now just make one change in the pattern. Its very simple.

Comment: Seems (\\d+)\\s+(years of experience|year experience) captures the first one but not the ones that has content between 'year' and 'experience'. Thx

Comment: Yes It's obvious. You have use escape character when used in JAVA. Just reform it as per your requirement. I have shared you links. Just spent some time to study it.